# Target the last relationship listed in a relationship field

Tags: relationships

I'm adding two div-wrappers around every 3 relationships. However, if the relationships count ends at 5, then I still need to add the ending div tags.

Here is the code -- where "IS_LAST" is what I seem to need to target, How do I target the last relationship called into the loop?

```
 {models}
      {if models:count == "1 || 4 || 7"}
        <div class="item  active" >
               <div class="row">
      {/if}

      <!-- other code in here-->

      {if models:count == "1 || 4 || 7" OR  models:count == IS_LAST}
            </div>
            </div>
      {/if}
    {/models}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 {models}
  {if models:count == "1 || 4 || 7"}
    <div class="item  active" >
           <div class="row">
  {/if}

  <!-- other code in here-->

  {if models:count == "1 || 4 || 7" OR  models:count == models:total_results}
        </div>
        </div>
  {/if}
{/models}
```

Comment: Ended up like this. Thanks.`{if models:count == 3 || models:count == 6 || models:count == 9 || models:count == 12}
   </div></div>
{/if}
     
{if models:count == models:total_results }
    {if models:count != 3  || models:count != 6 || models:count != 9 || models:count != 12}
 </div></div>
    {/if}
{/if}`